# Element-wise addition of lists of strings?

Tags: python, list

I want to merge some lists (same length) containing strings and adding space between the strings.

Input is:

```
rows = [['foo', '', '', 'bar', ''],
        ['', 'bar', '', 'foo', '']]
```

Result is:

```
result = ['foo', 'bar', '' 'bar foo', '']
```

I currently have a working code:

```
def merge_rows(rows):                                                           
    if len(rows) < 2:                                                           
         return None                                                             
    else:                                                                                                                                     
        rowSize = len(rows[0])                                                  
        result = [u'' for _ in range(rowSize)]                                  
        for row in rows:                                                        
        for i in range(rowSize):                                            
            if result[i] and row[i]:                                        
                result[i] = result[i] + ' ' + row[i]                        

                elif result[i]:                                                 
            continue                                                    

            else:                                                           
                result[i] = row[i]                                          

  return result
```

It works, but there got to be a better way.

Comment: If it works and you want it done better the right place is https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: The result is not valid

Comment: is was an indentation issue. fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [1]: rows = [['foo', '', '', 'bar', ''],
   ...:         ['', 'bar', '', 'foo', '']]

In [2]: [' '.join(i).strip() for i in zip(*rows)]

Out[2]: ['foo', 'bar', '', 'bar foo', '']
```

`.strip()` without parameters gets rid of all white space at the beginning and the end of the `string`

Answer (score 2):

`zip` the list and then use `join()` method get the string:

```
>>> rows = [['foo', '', '', 'bar', ''],
...         ['', 'bar', '', 'foo', ''],
...         ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']]
>>>
>>> [" ".join(i) for i in zip(*rows)]
['foo  1', ' bar 2', '  3', 'bar foo 4', '  5']
```

If you don't need the leading space, you can use `strip()` or `lstrip()` to remove them:

```
>>> [" ".join(i).strip() for i in zip(*rows)]
['foo  1', 'bar 2', '3', 'bar foo 4', '5']
```

Comment: sorry but these results have a leading space is them that is not acceptable

Comment: @King110 I update my answer , you can use `strip()` or `lstrip()` to remove them.